# Load markers from database for the visible area

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to load markers (custom overlay actually) from my database which contains the lat and the lng of each markers. I would like to load only the markers in the current visible area of the google map.

What I do is that I am getting the map bounds and calculate the max and min lat and lng. Each time I drag or change the zoom, I'm sending those bounds using ajax and then I retrieve the right markers from my database using a sql query which looks like this:

```
    AND lat BETWEEN :minLat AND :maxLat
    AND lng BETWEEN :minLng AND :maxLng
```

That is working fine... except when I'm currently looking between the 2 repeated worlds of a google map.

[image]

The sql query will not work anymore with those map bounds (sw and ne) because each bound are from their respective worlds. Then I won't retrieve any markers.

Example : Australia is about lng = 150, and in this case I would have
minLng = 25 (sw) and maxLng = 0 (ne)... obviously 150 is not between 0 and 25 even if I'm looking at Australia right now.

I have not seen any question on that particular problem...
Any idea to solve that? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT :** I finally solved my problem... here is what I did:

```
    // normal case
    if( $swLng < $neLng )
    {
        $ANDOR_lng = "AND";
    }
    // Case where world repeated
    else
    {
        $ANDOR_lng = "OR";
    }

    $dql = "SELECT MYSTUFF ...
            AND lat BETWEEN :latA AND :latB
            AND ( lng > :lngA ".$ANDOR_lng." lng < :lngB )";

        $parameters = array(
            'latA' => $swLat,
            'latB' => $neLat,
            'lngA' => $swLng,
            'lngB' => $neLng
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you would expect `w` (West longitude) to be smaller than `e` (East longitude), that is:

```
:minLng < :maxLng
```

However, but when the bounding box contains the meridian at 180 (or -180) this is not true. In those cases, this part of the query can never return true:

```
( lng > :minLng AND lng < :maxLng )
```

What you could do is swap `:minLng` and `:maxLng` so that the above assumption becomes true again:

```
if(:minLng > :maxLng) {
  :minLng, :maxLng = :maxLng, :minLng
}
```

If you look at your map above, that's consistent with what you're doing when drawing it: the `sw` corner has a greater longitude than the `ne` corner.

Warning: I haven't written PHP code for years, I don't know if you can actually do `a, b = b, a` to swap their values, I only know that works in Python, but you get the idea.

Comment: Cool, that's a nice way to reverse the match :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you uses the wrong bounds. You need to get the pixel bound and not the coordinate bounds. If you get the pixel bound then I think the query can work because there isn't such problem.